# Scroll to a new location of a given element inside a pivot grid that expands

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, selenium

I have a pivot table/grid where the user can expand and collapse rows. I am trying to come up with a way to scroll to an expanded row that appears after an expansion occurs. I normally can just use the following for scroll functions:

```
            Actions actions = new Actions(Browser);
        actions.MoveToElement(plusMinusIcon).Perform();
```

and this:

```
            var coordinates = plusMinusIcon.Location;
        ((IJavaScriptExecutor)Browser).ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0," + coordinates.Y + ")");
```

The above 2 methods for scrolling works just fine before any expansion occurs, when the page isnt too big and the scroll bar isnt too long. But if I expand a certain row, which then makes a lot more rows appear and makes the page huge, the scroll method does not scroll to the correct location, it instead scrolls somewhere else (keep in mind that the first expansion relied upon the scrolling function, so it did scroll just fine).
I noticed in debug mode when the scroll fails after the first expansion, that the test definitely scrolls the page a little bit, but it doesnt scroll to the element that I tell it to scroll to. What is going on? Will I have to do some kind of math to come up with new coordinates to scroll to?

Here is my test level line of code:

```
            Page.ClickExpansionIcon(VRptPage.VRptProjWOutActualsPvtGridBodyArea, "All Hours", 2);
```

Here is the method to scroll into view and then click the element:

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Expands the first instance in the grid of either All Days or All Hours header cell
    /// <param name="pvtGridBodyAreaElement">The element that contains the body elements of any pivot grid. i.e. "Page.VRptErrorMeasuresPvtGridBodyArea"</param>
    /// <param name="rowNumber">The exact row to the naked eye that the cell you want exists</param>
    /// <param name="timeFormatToExpand">Either 'All Days' or 'All Hours' 'All Dates' or 'All 1/4 Hours'"</param>
    /// </summary>
    public void ClickExpansionIcon(IWebElement pvtGridBodyAreaElement, string timeFormatToExpand, int rowNumber)
    {
        var cssSelectorString = string.Format("th[title='{0}']", timeFormatToExpand);

        // Find the element that can be expanded
        var expansionCapableElem = pvtGridBodyAreaElement.FindElements(By.CssSelector(cssSelectorString))[rowNumber - 1];

        // Find the + or - icons within the parent cell. 
        var plusMinusIcon = expansionCapableElem.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span[data-expand]"));

        var coordinates = plusMinusIcon.Location;
        ((IJavaScriptExecutor)Browser).ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0," + coordinates.Y + ")");

        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        plusMinusIcon.Click();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
```

Comment: Try this, highlight the plusMinusIcon before the scroll so you can see if the correct element was picked.

Comment: How do I highlight something in selenium? I'm pretty sure it is locating the correct element, because If I comment out the ScrollTo line of code, and instead manually scroll to the location of the element myself with my mouse, it then performs the click of the plusMinusIcon just fine

Answer (score 0):

This example is in C# but you get the idea..

```
  var jsDriver = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
  var element = // some element you find;
  string highlightJavascript = @"$(arguments[0]).css({ ""border-width"" : ""2px"", ""border-style"" : ""solid"", ""border-color"" : ""red"" });";
    jsDriver.ExecuteScript(highlightJavascript, new object[] { element });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was. So it didnt have anything to do with the dynamics of the pivot table. When the page was large enough for the scroll bar to scroll to the element, and still had more space to scroll further down, it would scroll just below the element. So to combat this, I had to scroll to the point just above the element:

```
            // Scroll to the point just above the plusMinusIcon
        var coordinateAboveIcon = plusMinusIcon.Location.Y - 100;
        ((IJavaScriptExecutor)Browser).ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0," + coordinateAboveIcon + ")");
```